# How can I draw dirac deltas with arrow heads with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, arrows, plot

I would like to draw this in pgfplots:

[image: deltas]

I've tried this, but I can't figure out how to get the arrowheads.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, axis x line=center, axis y line = center, 
  xmin=-3.5, xmax=3.5, ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5]
    \addplot+[ycomb,mark=triangle] plot coordinates {(-3,1) (3,-1)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: pgf delta]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just replace

```
\addplot+[ycomb,mark=triangle] plot coordinates {(-3,1) (3,-1)};
```

with

```
\draw[-latex,blue] (axis cs:3,0) -- (axis cs:3,1);
\draw[-latex,blue] (axis cs:-3,0) -- (axis cs:-3,1);
```

As you can read at page 187 of `pgfplots` manual you can access to the axis coordinates system by using `axis cs` and this allows you to put (I think) every TikZ code in your picture.
If you need to draw only vertical lines (like dirac's deltas) you can use the `\addplot` command but dividing positive and negative deltas:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, axis x line=center, axis y line = center, xmin=-3.5, xmax=3.5, ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5]
\addplot+[ycomb,mark=triangle,mark options={rotate=180}] plot coordinates {(3,-1) (2,-0.5)};
\addplot+[ycomb,mark=triangle,mark options={rotate=0}] plot coordinates {(-3,1) (-2,0.5)};
\draw[->] (axis cs:3,0) -- (axis cs:3,1);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there any way to modify the arrowheads of the pgfplots comb?  It's a bit cumbersome to have to draw each the arrows separately.

Comment: Updated my answer! I think that this is the best I can do

Answer (score 12):

If you need to have finer control over the plot marks (as you do in this case), you can use the `scatter` style in addition to `ycomb`. By enabling `scatter`, a new hook called `scatter/@pre marker code` becomes available that allows you to execute code before each mark is drawn.

The option `visualization depends on` allows you to perform mathematical operations on the current plot coordinates and store the result in a macro. I use it in the example below to determine the sign of the y-coordinate. This sign is then used in the `@pre marker code` to rotate only those arrows that have a negative y coordinate.

As Spike points out in a comment, the triangles extend beyond the line. This is due to the fact that marks are always centered on the coordinate. A quick fix for this is to add `yshift=-2pt` after the `rotate` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    dirac/.style={
        mark=triangle*,
        mark options={scale=2},
        ycomb,
        scatter,
        visualization depends on={y/abs(y)-1 \as \sign},
        scatter/@pre marker code/.code={\scope[rotate=90*\sign,yshift=-2pt]}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\makeatletter
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,xmin=-3,xmax=3,ymin=-2,ymax=2,grid=both]
\addplot +[dirac] coordinates {(-2,1) (1,-1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: scatter magic]

Comment: The question is not about the problem, but the arrows with the mark are not long as expected. There is a way to fix this?

Comment: @Spike: Good point! I've edited the answer to correct this.

Comment: You are quite great! :)

Answer (score 3):

another PSTricks solution with a variable number of coordinates:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\makeatletter
\def\psDirac{\pst@object{psDirac}}
\def\psDirac@i(#1,#2){\use@par\psline(#1,0)(#1,#2)%
  \@ifnextchar({\psDirac@i}{}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-3,-2.25)(3,2.25)
\psaxes[labels=none]{->}(0,0)(-3,-2)(3,2)[$t$,0][$f(t)$,90]
\psDirac[arrows=->,arrowscale=1.5,arrowinset=0,
         linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=blue](2.1,1)(2.5,-1)(-2,-1)(1,1)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice post.

Answer (score 2):

i changed it to the following:

```
\addplot +[mark=triangle*,
   mark options={scale=1},
   scatter,ycomb,
   visualization depends on={(y-abs(y))/abs(y-abs(y)) \as \sign},
   scatter/@pre marker code/.code={\scope[rotate=180*\sign,yshift=-2pt]}
   ] table[x=t_sig, y=sig] {\filename};
```

then it works for negative numbers other than -1.

Comment: Ah yes, good point. Or, slightly simpler, use `y/abs(y)-1` together with `rotate=90*\sign`.

Answer (score 2):

With PSTricks. Just for completeness. It can also accept infinite number of points.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-node}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\psdirac[1][]{\getnodelist{ps@dirac@name}{\ps@dirac[#1]}}
\def\ps@dirac[#1]{{%
    \psset{#1}%
    \multido{\i=0+1}{\the\numexpr\pst@args+1\relax}{%
    \psline(\PST@root\i|0,0)(\PST@root\i)
    }}}
\makeatother

\psset{arrows=->}
\def\dirac(#1,#2){\psline(#1,0)(#1,#2)}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-3)(5,4)
    \psaxes(0,0)(-1,-3)(4.5,3.5)[$t$,0][$f(t)$,90]
    \psdirac[linecolor=blue,linewidth=2\pslinewidth](0.5,-1)(2,3)(3.5,-2.5)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Warning:

I don't understand why `\PST@root` uses capital letters while `\pst@args` does not. It is a good naming convention. :-)

Comment: What is the difference between your post and the one @Herbert posted?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: I used a list of nodes but Herbert used a recursive method. There is an advantage when using a list of nodes because we can use the nodes for other purposes, for example, putting a circle on the diract arrow heads. :-)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: Defining a new macro as a PStricks object makes more sense because you have the same syntax as for other objects: `\psDirac[options]{arrows}(coors)...`. For simple macros one can also use `\pstnewobject`