# More: Generalised: Accessing the logic values of a TikZ coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, foreach, intersections, coordinates

This is a follow-up question to:  [Generalised: Accessing the logic values of a TikZ coordinate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23629/generalised-accessing-the-logic-values-of-a-tikz-coordinate).

In that question a PGFplot answer was suggested by jake.

I took that answer and modified it to the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

 \newcommand\xcoord[2][center]{{%
   \pgfpointanchor{#2}{#1}%
   \pgfgetlastxy{\ix}{\iy}%
   \pgfplotspointaxisorigin%
   \pgfgetlastxy{\ox}{\oy}
   \pgfmathparse{(\ix-\ox)/\pgfplotsunitxlength/1000}
   \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}
}

\begin{document}

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  domain=1:8.2,
  samples=150,
  no markers,
  axis lines=middle,
  enlarge x limits=upper,
  enlarge y limits=true,
  x axis line style={{name path global=xaxis}}
  ]
\addplot +[name path global=plot] {(x-2.07)*(x-4.09)*(x-5.72)*(x-8.04)};
\pgfplotsextra{ 
\fill [name intersections={of=xaxis and plot, name=i, total=\t}] 
  [red, every node/.style={black}] 
  (i-1) circle (2pt) node [pin={\xcoord{i-1}}] {}
  (i-2) circle (2pt) node [pin={\xcoord{i-2}}] {};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following:

[image: The result]

So the coordinates is off by a factor 10.

How would one correct that and I was wondering how one would access them through a foreach loop in stead of specifically making a node for each of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hm, something's not quite right with the `\pgfplotsunitxlength` macro. I've written a new macro `\xcoord` macro that works by extracting the values for the plot points (0,0) and (1,1) and using that for the unit vector. Note also that `\pgfplotspointorigin` points to the point where the two axes meet, not to the point (0,0), so the value was not only off by a factor of 10, but also by a shift of 1. I used the point (0,0) in the code below to correct for this.

You can just loop through the intersections by using `\foreach \n in {1,...,\t}`, where `\t` is the macro that holds the total number of intersections specified in `total=\t`.

There are sometimes issues with intersections being found twice if they lie exactly on one of the support points of the plot. In that case, you should adjust the `domain` slightly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

 \newcommand\xcoord[2][center]{{%
   % The actual point of interest
   \pgfpointanchor{#2}{#1}%
   \pgfgetlastxy{\ix}{\iy}%
   % (0,0)
   \pgfplotspointaxisxy{0}{0}%
   \pgfgetlastxy{\ox}{\oy}
   % (1,1)
   \pgfplotspointaxisxy{1}{1}%
   \pgfgetlastxy{\ux}{\uy}
   \pgfmathparse{(\ix-\ox)/(\ux-\ox)}
   \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}
}

\begin{document}

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xmin=0,
  domain=0:8.4,
  restrict y to domain=-100:50,
  samples=149,
  no markers,
  axis lines=middle,
  enlarge x limits=upper,
  enlarge y limits=true,
  x axis line style={{name path global=xaxis}}
  ]
\addplot +[name path global=plot] {(x-2.07)*(x-4.09)*(x-5.72)*(x-8.04)};
\pgfplotsextra{ 
\fill [name intersections={of=xaxis and plot, name=i, total=\t},
    red,
    every node/.style={black}] 
    \foreach \n in {1,...,\t} {
  (i-\n) circle (2pt) node [pin={\xcoord{i-\n}}] {}
  };
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: pgfplots intersections logical coordinates]

Comment: **TNX** it works exactly as you indicated.