# Generating an xtick for maximum value

Tags: pgfplots

I want to find the maximum value of a plot given by a function like in [How can I automatically mark local extrema with pgfplots and scatter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55349/how-can-i-automatically-mark-local-extrema-with-pgfplots-and-scatter?lq=1). Is there any way of writing the x-value on the x-acis automatically, too?

Comment: Do you want it to appear strictly as an extra tick or as an arbitrary style just to convey that info?

Comment: It don't has to be an extra tick. I will edit the question later to be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a solution.

I combined the dashed line in  [How can I automatically mark local extrema with pgfplots and scatter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55349/how-can-i-automatically-mark-local-extrema-with-pgfplots-and-scatter?lq=1) with the solution given in the first answer for [Generalised: Accessing the logic values of a TikZ coordinate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23629/generalised-accessing-the-logic-values-of-a-tikz-coordinate).