# Scaling and trimming white space from a pgfplots picture

Tags: pgfplots

In answering [How do I create a combined figure with two imported curves and draw around it with Tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170855/22413), I was able to make my own graph fill the space between two horizontal lines as seen [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170864/22413).  However, when I tried to import a `dat` file, I ran into difficulties.

**My first problem was scaling**.  I thought I could use the key `height` to fix the height of the image.  But it's not behaving as I thought it would:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\def\myimage#1{%%
    \begin{tikzpicture}%%[x=#1,y=#1]
      \begin{axis}[
        height=#1,
        hide axis,
        no markers,
      ]
      \addplot + table[x index=0, y index=1]{vp1.dat};
      \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- ++(6,0)
        (0,4) -- ++(6,0);
  \node[inner sep=0pt,draw,red] at (3,2) {\myimage{4cm}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I wanted it so that the red box's top and bottom should be flush with the black horizontal lines.

**My second problem** was getting rid of all the white space.  I would like the bounding box for the graph to fit as tightly as possible when I've hidden the axes.  In other words, the red border should be snug up against the blue of the graph.

Here's my `vp1.dat` file:

```
1 3
2 4
3 -5
4 6
```

Here's my `vp2.dat` file:

```
1 3
2 4
3 1
4 3
```

### **Update**

I have partial solutions to my questions but no combined solution.

> Solution to first problem

Regarding the **first problem**, I can get the `pgfplot` to fill the desired effect by using a combination of

```
scale only axis
height=#2
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\def\myimage#1#2{%%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        scale only axis,
        height=#2,
        hide axis,
        no markers,
      ]
      \addplot + table[x index=0, y index=1]{#1};
      \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- ++(6,0)
        (0,4) -- ++(6,0);
  \node[anchor=south] at (3,4) {\texttt{height=4cm} passed to \texttt{pgfplots}};
  \node[inner sep=0pt,draw,red] at (3,2) {\myimage{vp1.dat}{4cm}};
  \draw[<->] (6.25,0) -- ++(0,4) node [midway,right]{4cm};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which results in:

[image]

> Solution to second problem

Regarding the **second problem**, I can get the `pgfplot` to trim the extra white space that I do not want by using both

```
clip bounding box=upper bound
hide axis
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\def\myimage#1#2{%%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        clip bounding box=upper bound,
        hide axis,
        no markers,
      ]
      \addplot + table[x index=0, y index=1]{#1};
      \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[anchor=south] at (3,4.35) {graph fits snuggly in its bounding box};
  \node[inner sep=0pt,draw,red] at (3,2) {\myimage{vp1.dat}{4cm}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which results in:

[image]

> No solution for combined approach

But when I try to combine both methods, the height is not obeyed properly and I can't figure out how it's being calculated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\def\myimage#1#2{%%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        scale only axis,
        clip bounding box=upper bound,
        height=#2,
        hide axis,
        no markers,
      ]
      \addplot + table[x index=0, y index=1]{#1};
      \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- ++(6,0)
        (0,4) -- ++(6,0);
  \node[anchor=south] at (3,4) {combining \texttt{clipping} and \texttt{height}};
  \node[inner sep=0pt,draw,red] at (3,2) {\myimage{vp1.dat}{4cm}};
  \draw[<->] (6.25,0) -- ++(0,4) node [midway,right]{4cm};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which results in:

[image]

Comment: Related Questions: Perhaps [Specifying the width and height of a tikzpicture](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75449/specifying-the-width-and-height-of-a-tikzpicture) might be of some help for the first problem. And for the second question: [Is there a way to control whitespace around a TikZ picture?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57484/is-there-a-way-to-control-whitespace-around-a-tikz-picture).

Comment: @PeterGrill I'm not sure how the first link helps.  I'm already trying to use height, but it's not being obeyed.  Regarding the second link, the white space I'm objecting to is being generated by `pgfplots`.  With nodes in `tikz` you can specify `inner sep=0pt` to eliminate extra white space about the node.  But, I can't do that here.  For some reason `pgfplots` is maintaining the space dedicated to the axes even though I don't want to see them.  How can I eliminate that dedicated space?

Comment: @PeterGrill I know I could use clib, but it seems that that's more of a hack.  It seems to me that there should be some setting within `pgfplots` to achieve this.

Comment: I have found one answer:  the extra white space can be eliminated by setting `clip bounding box=upper bound` when used in conjunction with `hide axis`.

Comment: I answered those questions a while ago so don't know. But the first one basically was that it does _not_ make sense to specify a height for a `tikzpicture` as the drawing is done as per the `x`, `y` unit vectors of the `tikzpicture`.

Comment: @PeterGrill I understand that.  It's not the picture I for which I want to specify height, it's the `pgfplots` picture contained in a node.  It's to the `pgfplots`' `axis` environment that I'm passing `height`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want `enlargelimits=false` combined with `scale only axis` and `height`. `pgfplots` adds some whitespace around the plot by default, `enlargelimits=false` removes that.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\def\myimage#1#2{%%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        scale only axis,
        height=#2,
        hide axis,
        no markers,
        enlargelimits=false
      ]
      \addplot + table[x index=0, y index=1]{#1};
      \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- ++(6,0)
        (0,4) -- ++(6,0);
  \node[anchor=south] at (3,4) {\texttt{enlargelimits}, \texttt{scale only axis} and \texttt{height}};
  \node[inner sep=0pt,draw,red] at (3,2) {\myimage{vp1.dat}{4cm}};
  \draw[<->] (6.25,0) -- ++(0,4) node [midway,right]{4cm};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome.  This is the solution I was looking for.

Comment: Good answer. Just a note for the knowledge base: `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}` or newer will always activate `clip bounding box=upper bound`.

Answer (score 4):

I hope someone can come up with an answer which sticks entirely with `tikz` or `pgfplots` directives.

Here's a solution that lets me **both** clip the extra white space **and** set the box to the desired height.

My approach is to use `pgfplots` ability to clip the extra white space via

```
hide axis
clip bounding box=upper bound
```

Then I save the graph to a box (or, I could put it in its own `standalone` file).  Then I scale according to the size of the saved box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\def\myimageSnug#1{%%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        clip bounding box=upper bound,
        hide axis,
        hide axis,
        no markers,
      ]
      \addplot + table[x index=0, y index=1]{#1};
      \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\newsavebox{\myimagebox} 
\savebox{\myimagebox}{\myimageSnug{vp1.dat}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- ++(6,0)
        (0,4) -- ++(6,0);
  \node[anchor=south] at (3,4.35) {\footnotesize graph fits snuggly in its bounding box \textbf{and} it's the correct height};

  \node[inner sep=0pt,draw,red,scale=4cm/\ht\myimagebox] at (3,2) {\usebox{\myimagebox}};
\end{tikzpicture}%%

\end{document}
```

resulting in

[image]

Alternatively, I could use a `standalone` file named `graph_01`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    clip bounding box=upper bound,
    hide axis,
    hide axis,
    no markers,
  ]
  \addplot + table[x index=0, y index=1]{vp1.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And then import it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- ++(6,0)
        (0,4) -- ++(6,0);
  \node[anchor=south] at (3,4.35) {\footnotesize graph fits snuggly in its bounding box \textbf{and} it's the correct height};

  \node[inner sep=0pt,draw,red] at (3,2) {\includegraphics[height=4cm]{graph_01}};
\end{tikzpicture}%%

\end{document}
```