# Plot decorated arrows in pgf?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, pgfkeys, decorations, pgf-decorations

**Problematic**

I'd like to display a simple continuous graph and a set of vertical arrows whose height follow the shape of a function.

The following diagram of flows in TikZ has this decoration `\tikzset{flecheTV/.style={->,ultra thick,densely dotted, decorate,decoration={snake, amplitude=1mm,segment length=3mm,  pre length=3mm, post length=3mm}, color=orange}`

[image]

and I'd like to adapt it to pgf so that I can have automatically arrows proportional to the blue plot (not) as below

[image]

Unfortunately, so far

1. The arrows are not proportional to the blue plot
2. I want to show 10 arrows evenly displayed and it's not despite the `samples at = {0,...,10}`
3. the decoration is not applied as i'd wish
4. how can the arrow (the `ycomb` actually) start at `y=100` (with arrows that would be down when the blue curve goes below this level of 100) ?

I thought i could use decorated `ycomb` to mimic the diagram, but I cannot manage to pass the argument of the decoration to the plot.
Here is MWE (based on [plotting-arrows-programmatically-in-pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170660/plotting-arrows-programmatically-in-pgfplots?noredirect=1&lq=1))

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{
declare function={f(\x) =  rand*30*cos(\x) ;},
flecheTV/.style={->,ultra thick,densely dotted, decorate,decoration={snake, amplitude=1mm,segment length=3mm,  pre length=3mm, post length=3mm}, color=orange}
}

\pgfplotsset{
  mycomb/.style={flecheTV,mark=none,ycomb,}
}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetseed{2}
\def\Scale{0.8}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[domain= 0:10,
        samples at = {0,...,10},    
        ytick=100,
        separate axis lines,
        y axis line style= { draw opacity=0.0 },
    ]

    \addplot[very thin,opacity=0.8] {100};
    \addplot+[mark=none,blue, smooth,very thick,opacity=0.2] {f(x) + 100};
    \addplot+[mycomb,each nth point=1] {\Scale * f(x) +100}; 
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum**

Following multiple Q&A, I am reaching a great solution, more flexible than even initally expected (with now up threshold conditions on the curve to define the existence of arrows after this threshold is met or not).

Updated code based (99%) on @Frougon's great solution !!

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}     



\pgfmathsetseed{2}
\newcommand*{\myArrowScale}{1.0}
\def\Couleur{blue}
\def\KK{100}    %I keep that for constency of code of my side
%\newcommand*{\myBase}{\KK}
\def\BarE{120}
\def\BarEE{20}
\def\BarC{90}
%\newcommand*{\BarC}{90}
\def\BarP{60}
\def\CTF{5}
\tikzset{
  declare function={f(\x) = rand*70*sin(40*\x) ;},
  flecheTV/.style={
    ->, color=orange, ultra thick, densely dotted, decorate,decoration={snake, amplitude=1mm, segment length=3mm, pre length=3mm,
post length=3mm},
    opacity={#1},
  },
        fleche/.style={>=latex,very thick},
        flecheTF/.style={fleche, color=\Couleur!50!white},    
}

\newif\ifmyThresholdExceeded      % starts as false

\pgfplotstableset{
  create on use/x/.style={create col/expr={\pgfplotstablerow}},
  create on use/y/.style={create col/expr={f(\pgfplotstablerow)}},
  create on use/meta/.style={
    create col/assign/.code={%
      % Set the cell value depending on the \ifmyThresholdExceeded conditional
      \pgfplotstableset{create col/next content/.expanded={%
          \ifmyThresholdExceeded 0.1\else 1.0\fi}%
      }%
      \ifmyThresholdExceeded
      \else
        % \BarEE = threshold 
        \pgfmathparse{int(\pgfplotstablerow >= 0 &&
                          \pgfplotstablerow <= 9 &&
                          \thisrow{y} > \BarEE)}%
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
          \global\myThresholdExceededtrue
        \fi
      \fi
    },
  },
}

% Create a table with 11 rows (\pgfplotstablerow varies from 0 to 10).
\pgfplotstablenew[columns={x, y, meta}]{11}{\myTable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
      domain=0:10,
         ytick={\BarE,\KK,\BarC,\BarP},  
      separate axis lines,
      y axis line style={draw opacity=0.0},
      ]
    \addplot[very thin, opacity=0.8] {\KK};
    \addplot[very thick,green, opacity=0.8] {\BarE};
    \addplot[very thick,blue, opacity=0.8]  {\BarC};    
    \addplot[very thick,red, opacity=0.8]   {\BarP};  

    \addplot+[mark=none, blue, smooth, very thick, opacity=0.2]
      table[x=x, y expr={\thisrow{y} + \KK}] {\myTable};
    \addplot+[mark=none,
              quiver={u=0, v={
              %\CTF             %Fixed height arrow
              \thisrow{y}       %Proportionnal arrow
              + \KK - \BarC},
                      scale arrows=\myArrowScale,
                      every arrow/.append style={
                        /utils/exec={%
                          \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfplotspointmeta}%
                          \let\myOpacity\pgfmathresult
                        },
                      flecheTV/.expand once=\myOpacity,
                      }}]
      table[x=x, y expr=\BarC, point meta=\thisrow{meta}] {\myTable};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In the addendum, the comment `11 = threshold (this corresponds to 114)` should be updated to match the modified code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your arrows are drawn with new computations of *f*(*x*) for every *x* value, and since *f* uses `rand`, you obtain different values from those that were used for the curve. In order to solve this problem, I propose to dynamically create a table using `pgfplotstable`, store the needed *x* and *f*(*x*) values there, then draw both the curve and the arrows from these values. This way, `rand` is used exactly once for each data point.

The `/pgfplots/quiver` style makes it easy to draw the arrows starting from wherever you want—here, from (*x*, 100) for each value of *x*. Scaling the arrows is simply done with `scale arrows=0.8` (it is a `quiver` option). Of course, it would be possible to dynamically create one more column containing a particular signed value for each arrow and use it in the third `\addplot` command, but this doesn't seem necessary given this `scale arrows` option.

If you want to use your `\Scale` macro, you can of course write `scale arrows/.expand once=\Scale`, or even `scale arrows=\Scale`, since the `scale arrows` PGF key appears to expand its argument.

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}       % 1.16 works as well

\pgfmathsetseed{2}

\tikzset{
  declare function={f(\x) = rand*30*cos(50*\x) ;},
  flecheTV/.style={
    ->, color=orange, ultra thick, densely dotted, decorate,
    decoration={snake, amplitude=1mm, segment length=3mm, pre length=3mm,
                post length=3mm},
  },
}

\pgfplotstableset{
  create on use/x/.style={create col/expr={\pgfplotstablerow}},
  create on use/y/.style={create col/expr={f(\pgfplotstablerow)}},
}

% Create a table with 11 rows (\pgfplotstablerow varies from 0 to 10).
\pgfplotstablenew[columns={x, y}]{11}{\myTable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      domain=0:10,
      ytick=100,
      separate axis lines,
      y axis line style={draw opacity=0.0},
      ]
    \addplot[very thin, opacity=0.8] {100};
    \addplot+[mark=none, blue, smooth, very thick, opacity=0.2]
      table[x=x, y expr={\thisrow{y} + 100}] {\myTable};
    \addplot+[mark=none, quiver={u=0, v=\thisrow{y}, scale arrows=0.8,
                                 every arrow/.append style={flecheTV}}]
      table[x=x, y expr=100] {\myTable};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Addendum: conditional arrow opacity

This addresses your question in [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/540606/plot-decorated-arrows-in-pgf/540635?noredirect=1#comment1365487_540635). Given the random seed from the question, in order to see something, I'll give opacity 0.1 to all arrows as soon as we've seen at least one value for function *f* that is greater than 14 (i.e., 114 if you take into account the offset 100) *among the values for points 1, 2, ..., 9*, where the first point is number 0 (as per your request). In order to do this, we:

- modify the `flecheTV` style so that it accepts the arrow opacity as its only argument;
- add a new column to the generated table where we store the desired opacity depending on the current *f*(*x*) value and those seen so far;
- use this column as `point meta`;
- convert each point meta value to fixed format (numerical point meta is in the format of the PGF `fpu` library, e.g., `1Y1.0e0]`);
- pass the result to the modified `flecheTV` style.

If you replace `\ifnum\pgfplotstablerow<1` with `\ifnum\pgfplotstablerow<4`, you'll see that the fourth point doesn't trigger the above-threshold condition anymore, since its number is 3 (starting from 0).

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}       % 1.16 works as well

\pgfmathsetseed{2}

\tikzset{
  declare function={f(\x) = rand*30*cos(50*\x) ;},
  flecheTV/.style={
    ->, color=orange, ultra thick, densely dotted, decorate,
    decoration={snake, amplitude=1mm, segment length=3mm, pre length=3mm,
                post length=3mm},
    opacity={#1},
  },
}

\newif\ifmyThresholdExceeded      % starts as false

\pgfplotstableset{
  create on use/x/.style={create col/expr={\pgfplotstablerow}},
  create on use/y/.style={create col/expr={f(\pgfplotstablerow)}},
  create on use/meta/.style={
    create col/assign/.code={%
      \ifmyThresholdExceeded
      \else
        \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow<1
        \else
          \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow>9
          \else
            % 14 = threshold (this corresponds to 114)
            \pgfmathparse{int(\thisrow{y} > 14)}%
            \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
              \global\myThresholdExceededtrue
            \fi
          \fi
        \fi
      \fi
      % Set the cell value depending on the \ifmyThresholdExceeded conditional
      \pgfplotstableset{create col/next content/.expanded={%
          \ifmyThresholdExceeded 0.1\else 1.0\fi}%
      }%
    },
  },
}

% Create a table with 11 rows (\pgfplotstablerow varies from 0 to 10).
\pgfplotstablenew[columns={x, y, meta}]{11}{\myTable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      domain=0:10,
      ytick=100,
      separate axis lines,
      y axis line style={draw opacity=0.0},
      ]
    \addplot[very thin, opacity=0.8] {100};
    \addplot+[mark=none, blue, smooth, very thick, opacity=0.2]
      table[x=x, y expr={\thisrow{y} + 100}] {\myTable};
    \addplot+[mark=none,
              quiver={u=0, v=\thisrow{y}, scale arrows=0.8,
                      every arrow/.append style={
                        /utils/exec={%
                          \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfplotspointmeta}%
                          \let\myOpacity\pgfmathresult
                        },
                        flecheTV/.expand once=\myOpacity,
                      }}]
      table[x=x, y expr=100, point meta=\thisrow{meta}] {\myTable};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: the following piece of code used to initialize values in the `meta` column:

```latex
\ifmyThresholdExceeded
\else
  \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow<1
  \else
    \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow>9
    \else
      % 14 = threshold (this corresponds to 114)
      \pgfmathparse{int(\thisrow{y} > 14)}%
      \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
        \global\myThresholdExceededtrue
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
\fi
```

can be replaced with:

```latex
\ifmyThresholdExceeded
\else
  \pgfmathparse{int(\pgfplotstablerow >= 1 &&
                    \pgfplotstablerow <= 9 &&
                    \thisrow{y} > 14)}%
  \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
    \global\myThresholdExceededtrue
  \fi
\fi
```

The latter is probably a tiny bit slower than the former, but this technique may be more convenient in case you need to write complex conditions (in the argument of `\pgfmathparse`, you can use boolean operators, parentheses and all other things supported by `pgfmath`).

## Addendum 2: minor variations

This addresses questions in [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/540606/plot-decorated-arrows-in-pgf/540635?noredirect=1#comment1365801_540635):

- `\newcommand*{\myBase}{100}`, `\newcommand*{\myArrowBase}{90}` and `\newcommand*{\myArrowScale}{1.0}` and `v={\thisrow{y} + \myBase - \myArrowBase}` in the `quiver` options to change where the arrows start from. Beware, this can be confusing because now, a zero-length arrow doesn't mean that the `cos` was equal to zero. Put both bases to 100 to get back to the previous situation. Feel free to set `\myArrowScale` to `0.8` or whatever when you've understood how things are displayed (this addresses your 1).
- `\pgfplotstablerow >= 0` instead of `\pgfplotstablerow >= 1` in the test so that the first point can trigger the condition computation (this addresses your 3);
- `\pgfplotstableset{create col/next content/...}` moved before doing the test (this addresses your 2, but in order to have the first arrow dimmed, you of course need to undo the previous item since it delays the arrow dimming);
- Threshold changed from 14 to 11.77 to be just below the value for the first point (its value is 11.772903; change the threshold to 11.78 and the first point can't trigger the condition anymore).

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}       % 1.16 works as well

\pgfmathsetseed{2}

\newcommand*{\myBase}{100}
\newcommand*{\myArrowBase}{90}
\newcommand*{\myArrowScale}{1.0}

\tikzset{
  declare function={f(\x) = rand*30*cos(50*\x) ;},
  flecheTV/.style={
    ->, color=orange, ultra thick, densely dotted, decorate,
    decoration={snake, amplitude=1mm, segment length=3mm, pre length=3mm,
                post length=3mm},
    opacity={#1},
  },
}

\newif\ifmyThresholdExceeded      % starts as false

\pgfplotstableset{
  create on use/x/.style={create col/expr={\pgfplotstablerow}},
  create on use/y/.style={create col/expr={f(\pgfplotstablerow)}},
  create on use/meta/.style={
    create col/assign/.code={%
      % Set the cell value depending on the \ifmyThresholdExceeded conditional
      \pgfplotstableset{create col/next content/.expanded={%
          \ifmyThresholdExceeded 0.1\else 1.0\fi}%
      }%
      \ifmyThresholdExceeded
      \else
        % 11.77 = threshold (this corresponds to function value \myBase + 11.77)
        \pgfmathparse{int(\pgfplotstablerow >= 0 &&
                          \pgfplotstablerow <= 9 &&
                          \thisrow{y} > 11.77)}%
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
          \global\myThresholdExceededtrue
        \fi
      \fi
    },
  },
}

% Create a table with 11 rows (\pgfplotstablerow varies from 0 to 10).
\pgfplotstablenew[columns={x, y, meta}]{11}{\myTable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      domain=0:10,
      ytick=\myBase,
      separate axis lines,
      y axis line style={draw opacity=0.0},
      ]
    \addplot[very thin, opacity=0.8] {\myBase};
    \addplot+[mark=none, blue, smooth, very thick, opacity=0.2]
      table[x=x, y expr={\thisrow{y} + \myBase}] {\myTable};
    \addplot+[mark=none,
              quiver={u=0, v={\thisrow{y} + \myBase - \myArrowBase},
                      scale arrows=\myArrowScale,
                      every arrow/.append style={
                        /utils/exec={%
                          \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfplotspointmeta}%
                          \let\myOpacity\pgfmathresult
                        },
                      flecheTV/.expand once=\myOpacity,
                      }}]
      table[x=x, y expr=\myArrowBase, point meta=\thisrow{meta}] {\myTable};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you take the above code and just replace `\thisrow{y} > 11.77` with `\thisrow{y} > 11.78`, the first point (number 0, value 11.772903) doesn't trigger the condition anymore, even though it is tested due to the `\pgfplotstablerow >= 0` partial condition used here. The fourth point (number 3, value 14.5334485) will however trigger it. Since in this addendum 2, we are delaying the dimming by one data point, the output will be as follows:

[image]

Comment: Wow ! Merci @frougon ! I'll learn more about quiver (it seems  complicated but you made it super clear). This code is indeed extremely flexible to do what I need.

Comment: No, `quiver` is very simple: current position gives the arrow origin, `u` option gives arrow x coord and `v` option the arrow y coord; then the `scale arrows` factor is applied, and voilà! :-) In an earlier version (before noticing the `scale arrows` option), I created an additional column with: `\pgfplotstableset{my arrow scale/.initial=0.8, create on use/arrow/.style={create col/expr={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/my arrow scale}*\thisrow{y}}}} ... \pgfplotstablenew[columns={x, y, arrow}]{11}{\myTable}` (in case this is helpful).

Comment: it's a discovery for me !
May I ask you one last thing (here or in another question). The last element I'd need is actually to incorporate a threshold level `(T)`. If the blue curve is above `T` (let's say `T=120`) at one of the points from 1 to 9, all the following  arrows become "inactive" (effectively, `opacity = 0.1`)

Comment: The  `scale arrow` option is indeed super useful.

Comment: I have updated the answer to implement the arrow opacity that depends on a threshold condition, as you asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/540606/plot-decorated-arrows-in-pgf/540635?noredirect=1#comment1365487_540635).

Comment: Fantastic! You made my day in this lock down period, I can go back to work. Merci :)

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb I am totally agree with you ...fantastic.

Comment: Thanks! I've added another way to write the condition in the second example, which should be easier for complex conditions.

Comment: It's indeed very convenient vs the série of if. Thank you for your cristal clear answer. I learnt a lot:) A bientôt.

Comment: You're welcome. :-)

Comment: Small optimization: I replaced `\edef\myOpacity{\pgfmathresult}` with `\let\myOpacity\pgfmathresult` (`\pgfmathresult` already contains the opacity in decimal notation: there is no need to try to expand the tokens inside—which are all unexpandable, BTW).

Comment: I've been working on your super short and optimized code since yesterday. It's dense :) May I ask you : 1/ I don't see how I can make the arrow start @ 90 vs 100 (i'll need to play with that at some point). 2/ Once the threshold is hit (let's say at point 3), how can I display the arrow and then not display them anymore? 3/ I don't manage not to display the arrow at the starting point 0. Merci again !

Comment: There is nothing special about the 100. Do you want only the arrows to start from 90, or do you want 90 to be the new “reference point”?

Comment: You're correct to distinguish, I'd like to have the arrow start @ 90.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107223/discussion-between-julien-elie-taieb-and-frougon).

Answer (score 5):

Here is another way of doing this, using `tikz` `intersection`s library.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}

\tikzset{
declare function={f(\x) =  rand*30*cos(\x) ;},
flecheTV/.style={->,ultra thick,densely dotted, decorate,decoration={snake, amplitude=1mm,segment length=3mm,  pre length=3mm, post length=3mm}, color=orange}
}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetseed{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Scale}{0.8}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[domain= 0:10,
        samples at = {0,...,10},    
        ytick=100,
        separate axis lines,
        y axis line style= { draw opacity=0.0 },
    ]

    \addplot[very thin,opacity=0.8] {100};
    \addplot+[mark=none,blue, smooth,very thick,opacity=0.2, name path=f] {f(x) + 100};
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,10}{
        \path[name path=tempxplot] (axis cs:#1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:#1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
        \draw[name intersections={of=tempxplot and f},flecheTV] (axis cs:#1,100) -- ($(axis cs:#1,100)!\Scale!(intersection-1)$);
    }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM** : Took me a while to figure it out, but here is a version where a threshold for arrow length can be taken into account.
This action is based on the `let` operation.

Note that the threshold is expressed in terms of `pt` and not as `axis` units.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}

\tikzset{
declare function={f(\x) =  rand*30*cos(\x) ;},
flecheTV/.style={->,ultra thick,densely dotted, decorate,decoration={snake, amplitude=1mm,segment length=3mm,  pre length=3mm, post length=3mm}, color=orange}
}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetseed{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Scale}{0.8}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ArrowThreshold}{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[domain= 0:10,
        samples at = {0,...,10},    
        ytick=100,
        separate axis lines,
        y axis line style= { draw opacity=0.0 },
    ]

    \addplot[very thin,opacity=0.8] {100};
    \addplot+[mark=none,blue, smooth,very thick,opacity=0.2, name path=f] {f(x) + 100};
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,10}{
        \path[name path=tempxplot] (axis cs:#1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:#1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
        % Create a path operation starting with computing the required intersection
        \path[name intersections={of=tempxplot and f}] (axis cs:#1,100) -- (intersection-1)
        % Place a coordinate at the origin of the path (just for convenience)
        coordinate[pos=0] (arrowstart) 
        % Place a coordinate at the 80% of the path (just for convenience)
        coordinate[pos=\Scale]  (arrowend)
        % Based on the predefined coordinates, compute the length of the arrow in pt then attribute opacity based on the threshold
        let \p1 = ($(arrowend)-(arrowstart)$),
            \n1 = {ifthenelse(abs(\y1)>\ArrowThreshold,1,0)} 
        in (arrowstart) edge[flecheTV,opacity=\n1] (arrowend);
    }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting to see how you played with the pgf keys.

Comment: May I ask you how intersection would handle the second part (it was added) regarding the conditional display of the arrows once a threshold is met?

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb, just posted un update based on your last demand

Comment: Merci @BambOo ! I am working on your code :)  changing the `\pgfmathsetseed{}`, function from `cos` to `sin` and the `y` shift from 100 to 90. I must be doing something wrong but don't you think the approach by `cm` twisted everything once you decide to add for instance `ymax =150` ?

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb, I have to admit I am not sure how to do this using `axis` units. It really depends why you want these arrows discarded. If it is for *physical* reasons, then it makes sense to remove them in terms of `axis`, hence physical units. However, if you want to remove them just to avoid to small ugly arrows then it makes more sense to test against *true*, paper dimensions don't you think ?

Comment: It's more for economic reasons. The arrows represent  cash flows. They can be proportional to the (blue) indicator or fixed. Once the indicator goes beyond the threshold, they stop.

Comment: Well, in that case, I do not think my solution is suited for this part